# CLion error when opening an AzerothCore project

Tags: clion, azerothcore

I've tried to open an [AzerothCore](https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk) project using [CLion](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/?from=AzerothCore) and when the IDE starts I get the following errors:

> Problems were encountered while collecting compiler information:
>       cc1plus: fatal error: .../azerothcorde-wotlk/cmake-build-debug/src/common/sharedPCH.h: No such file or directory
>       cc1plus: fatal error: .../azerothcorde-wotlk/cmake-build-debug/src/common/Collision/collisionPCH.h: No such file or directory
>       cc1plus: fatal error: .../azerothcorde-wotlk/cmake-build-debug/cmake-build-debug/src/server/authserver/authPCH.h: No such file or directory
>       cc1plus: fatal error: .../azerothcorde-wotlk/cmake-build-debug/cmake-build-debug/src/server/game/gamePCH.h: No such file or directory
>       cc1plus: fatal error: .../azerothcorde-wotlk/cmake-build-debug/cmake-build-debug/src/server/scripts/ScriptPCH.h: No such file or directory
>       cc1plus: fatal error: .../azerothcorde-wotlk/cmake-build-debug/cmake-build-debug/src/server/worldserver/worldPCH.h: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the IDE solved the issue for me.